# How to log on website using LDAP

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-mvc, ldap

I have very limited knowledge on LDAP so please forgive my saying anything stupid.

I try to design a module that allows user to `log on` current `Spring application` via `LDAP`. I guess if user log on the system via LDAP so the Spring application should be able to identify the user by the `uid` or something so user no long need to log on the system anymore.

The development system is on Windows 7, and I have installed `Apache DS` and `Apache DS Studio` on my STS, also follow online tutorial to setup proper `role` and `user` in a new partition. Now the questions are:

```
How can I "link" my web application to the LDAP user? 

And how can I log on LDAP server with one of the user credential?
```

Please share any advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Spring already, you should look into Spring Security (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/index.html).

Spring Security allows you to secure Spring applications in a variety of ways with LDAP being just one (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html).